# Is there a technical name for the number of implications between propositions?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Given 2 True/False boolean propositions $\mathcal{P}_1\{x_1\}$ and $\mathcal{P}_2\{x_2\}$, where $x_i\in \{T,F\}$

there are 7 possible relations between $\mathcal{P}_1\{x_1\}$ and $\mathcal{P}_2\{x_2\} \\$

**0 implications:**

1) $\mathcal{P}_1$ bears no relation to $\mathcal{P}_2$ and by contraposition $\mathcal{P}_2$ bears no relation to $\mathcal{P}_1 \\$

**1 implication:**

2) $\mathcal{P}_1\{T\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2\{T\}$ and by contraposition $\mathcal{P}_2\{F\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1\{F\}$

3) $\mathcal{P}_1\{T\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2\{F\}$ and by contraposition $\mathcal{P}_2\{T\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1\{F\}$

4) $\mathcal{P}_1\{F\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2\{T\}$ and by contraposition $\mathcal{P}_2\{F\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1\{T\}$

5) $\mathcal{P}_1\{F\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2\{F\}$ and by contraposition $\mathcal{P}_2\{T\} \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1\{T\} \\$

**2 implications:**

6) $\mathcal{P}_1\{T\} \Longleftrightarrow \mathcal{P}_2\{T\}$ alternatively $x_1 = x_2$

7) $\mathcal{P}_1\{T\} \Longleftrightarrow \mathcal{P}_2\{T\}$ alternatively $x_1 \neq x_2 \\$

- - Question: Are there any technical names for these groups of relations, and have I missed any relations? I'm pretty sure this is an exhaustive list.

I would guess that the *2 implications* are called bijections.

I can't think of a name for the *1 implication*

I think the *0 implications* are called mutually exclusive.

- I've never studied propositional calculus

Thanks in advance for any help and pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is no there is not.